# Modernizr: Testing for WebGL vs WebGL Exentions

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, modernizr

I'm using **THREE.js** scenes and graphic objects on my webpage. I know, at the least, **THREE.js** utilizes **WebGL**.

I'd like to utilize **Modernizr** to check the current browser for compatability with **WebGL** and, if the browser doesn't have it, prompt a message to the user.

When selecting the [browser features](https://modernizr.com/download?webgl-setclasses) to have **Modernizr** test for, I see two features that relate to my goal

**WebGL:** *Detects for WebGL in the browser.*

**WebGl Extentions**: *Detects support for OpenGL extensions in WebGL. It's `true` if the WebGL extensions API is supported, then exposes the supported extensions as subproperties, e.g.:*

So in order for **THREE.js** to work, do I need to test for **WebGL Extentions** and **WebGL** *or* simply just **WebGL**?

Answer (score 3):

It depends whether you're using features that require extensions. Three.js itself doesn't need any extensions. Certain things like shadows probably run faster if you `WEBGL_depth_texture` extension.

If you don't know what extensions you personally need consider inserting some code to hide them and see if your app still runs

Example:

```
// disable all extensions

WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getExtension = function() {
  return null;
}
WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getSupportedExtensions = function() {
  return [];
}

// now init three.js
```

If you want to allow specific extensions you could do something like this

```
var allowedExtensions = [
  "webgl_depth_texture",
  "oes_texture_float",
];

WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getExtension = function(origFn) {
  return function(name) {
    if (allowedExtensions.indexOf(name.ToLowerCase()) >= 0) {
      return origFn.call(this, name);
    }
    return null;
  };
}(WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getExtension);

WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getSupportedExtensions = function(origFn) {
  return function() {
    return origFn.call(this).filter(function(name) {
      return allowedExtensions.indexOf(n) >= 0;
    });
  };
}(WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getSupportedExtensions);
```